# Why HashMaps 10 get() call performance not 10 times worst than a single get() performance

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, jvm, benchmarking

I have a *hashmap* field with `100_000` entries and two methods A and B.

- *Method A* : Calls `map.get()` one time with a random key
- *Method B* : Calls `map.get()` ten times with **a** random key(same key every time)

I configured these two methods with `JMH` to run many times (whole test took more than 1 hour on my Macbook pro) and measure throughputs and it turns out *Method A* is only about twice as fast as *Method B*. I was hoping 10x of a difference.

I was not able to explain this behaviour, Here are the results

```
# Run complete. Total time: 01:08:36

Benchmark                           Mode  Throughput           Units
TestClass.benchmark_with_one_get   thrpt   23819.007   operations/ms
TestClass.benchmark_with_ten_gets  thrpt   12021.025   operations/ms
```

Then I wanted to experiment more, I overrode the `hashCode()` method of the *hashmap*s key (`TestKey`) with a constant function (always return integer `5`) to essentially make the hashmap a list. Then only I could see the results I was expecting. I didn't run the whole test since it takes 6+ hours to complete, but here are rough results(From first 2 iterations only)

```
Benchmark                           Mode   Throughput             Units
TestClass.benchmark_with_one_get   thrpt      244.266      operations/s
TestClass.benchmark_with_ten_gets  thrpt       24.981      operations/s
```

And here's the original class I used to benchmark.

```
package test.benchmark;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class TestClass {

    private Map<TestKey, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    private List<TestKey> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int test1 = 0;
    private int test2 = 0;

    public TestClass() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
            TestKey testKey = new TestKey(i);
            map.put(testKey, i);
            keyList.add(new TestKey(random.nextInt(100_001)));
        }
    }

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int tmp = random.nextInt(100_001);
        test1 = tmp;
        test2 = tmp;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    @Measurement(iterations = 20, time = 10)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    public boolean benchmark_with_one_get() {

        TestKey testKey = keyList.get(test1);
        map.get(testKey);
        test1++;
        if (test1 >= 100_000) {
            test1 = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    @Measurement(iterations = 20, time = 10)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    public boolean benchmark_with_ten_gets() {

        TestKey testKey = keyList.get(test2);
        map.get(testKey);
        map.get(testKey);
        map.get(testKey);
        map.get(testKey);
        map.get(testKey);
        map.get(testKey);
        map.get(testKey);
        map.get(testKey);
        map.get(testKey);
        map.get(testKey);
        test2++;
        if (test2 >= 100_000) {
            test2 = 0;
        }

        return true;
    }


    public class TestKey {
        private int key;

        public TestKey(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public int getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return obj instanceof TestKey && ((TestKey) obj).key == this.key;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 31 * 17 + key;
        }

    }
}
```

Any ideas, explanations are welcome. thanks

Comment: What happens if you increase the number of warmup iterations to 100?

Comment: Just ran the test again with 100 warmups, result is still the same ```A - 23374.720```  and ```B - 11671.093```

Comment: `benchmark_with_ten_gets` does obviously much less than 10 `benchmark_with_one_get`. Other operations - `keyList.get()`, updating `test2` and consuming benchmark result - are not free. Furthermore, getting 10 random keys and 10 same keys in a row don't take the same time (consider [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) etc.)

Comment: Your `TestKey` class is atypical as a hashmap key. It should override `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: @user207421 : Yes, I also had this concern and ran again with overridden ```hashCode()``` and ```equals()``` methods. But the results were the same

Comment: @Holger : Yeah I should've set the same starting value, this was a mistake clearly. Ran again with the same value, no change in results whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's somewhat disappointing that the JVM didn't optimize away the access entirely since you don't use the result of `map.get(testKey);`

Or a least [CSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) multiple calls to the same function.  Maybe some Common-Subexpression-Elimination happened under the hood across the separate `map.get` calls.  e.g. at least the result of the `hashCode()` method on your `testKey` can be reused for each call.

Or maybe none of that happens.

**The entire effect is fairly easily explained by cache locality**: the first access is expensive because it probably misses in cache.  Later accesses are very cheap: reloading something you just loaded can hit in L1d cache.  And out-of-order execution can interleave all this independent work so the "waiting" for the same result 10 times basically happens in parallel, depending on how much native machine code actually runs for each call by the time JIT optimization is done with it.  (A Skylake CPU for example has a reorder buffer size of 224 uops.)

Accessing the same hash with the same key will access the same memory locations.

---

**Making the hash map degenerate** so it turns into a linked-list search means each access takes a really long time, more than the out-of-order execution window size, so even a modern high-end CPU can't find and exploit the instruction-level parallelism and interleave the work.

**It also means that you touch so much memory traversing that linked list that the start of it isn't still hot in cache by the time you get to the end.**  So later traversals don't benefit from having already "blazed a trail" and getting data hot in cache.

Traversing a linked list that's not hot in cache is very very bad for a CPU.  It can't get started on the next load until it knows the right address, but that's dependent on the load it's waiting for.  So only 1 load can be in flight at once, no memory-level parallelism.

(Unlike an array where a loop doing `array[i++]` can compute the next address cheaply while the data is still in flight.  A modern x86 such as Skylake has something like 12 "line fill buffers"; it can track 12 outstanding requests for different cache lines in/out in parallel.  Multiple accesses to a non-degenerate hashmap with different keys can take advantage of this if the code for each access + use is short enough that out-of-order exec can get started on the 2nd while the first is still in flight.  (Branch prediction + speculative execution will let this work even if the code branches on the possibility of a hash collision for that bucket))

---

**Key points:**

- Computations don't have a fixed cost you can just add up.  At a small enough scale, throughput vs. latency matters for pipelined / out-of-order execution.
- Cache is important: when cache + branch prediction enters the picture, re-**running the same code on the same data can go much faster the 2nd time**.  (For small amounts of data, e.g. fast per-core 32kiB L1d cache and 256kiB L2 cache is common on x86.  Skylake-Xeon has 1MiB L2 cache per core.)
- Compilers (might be) smart and can optimize away redundant work in overly simplistic benchmark attempts.

  A JIT-compiled language like Java also has the effect that code doesn't even get fully optimized until it's been run many times, but that's a separate thing from the above effects that apply even to machine code.